# How can i use MySql in my college when they dont accept port 3306?

Tags: mysql, port

In college i am doing programming coursework which requires MySql , however my college wont allow port 3306, they don't have room to store a small server and all the PC's have the same domain, is there any other way i can connect to MySql on the college PC's without using my laptop. I can use my phone as a Wi-Fi Hotspot but that's about all i can do for it.
Thanks

Comment: They won't allow a server on port 3306, or allow any connections to that port?   Have you tried running Mysql on an alternate port?   What ports are actually available to you?

Comment: I'm not sure, ill try asking what ports are available for me, but the server in which i'm hosting the database uses port 3306 and i'm not sure how i can change that, the host's are on freemysqlhosting.net

Comment: Based on that, it sounds like they don't allow outbound connections to port 3306.   Rather than use an externally hosted MySql, you will probably have to run MySql on your own computer instead.

Comment: You think i can use TeamViewer from my laptop, to my phone then use their chrome to link my phone screen to the desktop? Then again i don't know if its worth the hassle, i'm not allowed to bring my laptop to college.

Comment: Is SSH allowed?  There's port forwarding ability over SSH tunnels ...

Comment: I'm not sure but i could ask them.